# Rails ActiveRecord equivalent to Hibernate load()?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm new to Rails, from a Java background.

I have some troubles on many-to-many (through 3rd join table) associations.

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

In my rest method, i will past Physician id and Patient id. To setup Physician and Patient connection I use

```
py = Physician.find(params[:physician_id])
pa = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
py.patients<<pa
```

I mean, here, two select and one insert seems too costy for me.
Is there anyway just trigger one insert since i already know physician and patient exist in db.

In hibernate, there is load() function which create the proxy object of loaded model without hitting DB.

```
Physician py = session.load(1);
Patient pa = session.load(2);
AppointmentDao.save(new Appointment(py,pa));
```

Thanks for any answer. And any suggestions on Rails philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `Appointment.create physician_id: 1, parient_id: 2`